# Polymorphism with different method signatures

Tags: objective-c, polymorphism

I have a group of classes (say for validation rules).  Each one returns a true or false.

I use id and call a method signature for each one of the classes and get the results allowing me to dynamically create validation rules.

Worked great until...

I have a new class that takes an extra parameter to come up with its validation.

What is the best way to deal with this?

Modify every other classes method signature to take a parameter that they don't need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the most appropriate course of action is to abstract your parameter passing into an object that can have a variable profile of variables.

Of course, more simply, Objective-C does allow for a variable parameter list much like C:

```
void method(int a, ...)     // in C
- (void) method:(id) firstObject, ...  // in ObjC
```

Apple has [Technical Q&A](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2005/qa1405.html) on the very subject.

Comment: Yes, putting the variables into an NSDictionary would let the various classes pick & choose what they're interested in.